# Approximation of the Gaussian Mills' ratio

Tags: probability-distributions, inequalities, gaussian

Let $R(t) = \frac{1 - \Phi(t)}{\varphi(t)}$ where $\Phi, \varphi$ represent the CDF and PDF of the standard Normal distribution, respectively.

I am interested in approximations of the function for $t > 0$,
$$
f(t) = R(t)(1 + t^2) - t
$$
Based on numerical work, it seems as though the function $f$ is quite close to the function
$$
g(t) = \frac{2}{t^3 +2 \sqrt{2/\pi}}, 
$$
in the sense that for two positive constants $c_1 < c_2$ we have
$$
c_1 g(t) \leq f(t) \leq c_2 g(t) \quad \mbox{for all}~t > 0. 
$$
The best possible constants seem to be, again based on numerics, $(c_1, c_2) \approx (0.403603, 1)$. Is it possible to show this formally? I tried to manipulate the asymptotic expansions of the complementary error function but was unable to make progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r:=f/g$. Then
$$r=\frac{f_0}{g_0},$$
where
$$f_0(t):=\frac{f(t)}{(1+t^2)e^{t^2/2}},\quad 
g_0(t):=\frac{g(t)}{(1+t^2)e^{t^2/2}}.$$
Then the "derivative ratio"
$$\rho(t):=\frac{f'_0(t)}{g'_0(t)}
=\frac{\pi  t^6+4 \sqrt{2 \pi } t^3+8}{t \left(2 \sqrt{2 \pi }
   \left(t^2+3\right)+\pi  t \left(t^4+6 t^2+3\right)\right)},$$
so that $\rho$ is a rational function, with
$$p(t):=\rho'(t)\, \frac{\sqrt{\pi } t^2 \left(2 \sqrt{2} \left(t^2+3\right)+\sqrt{\pi } t
   \left(t^4+6 t^2+3\right)\right)^2}{6 \left(t^2+1\right)} \\ 
=2 \pi ^{3/2} t^7-\sqrt{2} \pi  t^6+2 \sqrt{2} \pi  t^4-8 \sqrt{\pi } t^3-8
   \sqrt{\pi } t-8 \sqrt{2}. $$
For the polynomial $p$ and some real root $t_p\approx1.24$ of $p$, we have $p<0$ on $(0,t_p)$ and $p>0$ on $(t_p,\infty)$. So, $\rho$ is down-up on $(0,\infty)$ -- that is, for some $c\in[0,\infty]$ we have that $\rho$ is decreasing on $(0,c)$ and increasing on $(c,\infty)$. Also, $f_0(\infty-)=0=g_0(\infty-)$.

So, by [Proposition 4.3](https://eudml.org/doc/128522), $r$ is down-up on $(0,\infty)$. Also, $r(0)=1=r(\infty-)$. Thus, the desired result follows. $\quad\Box$

---

To bound numerically the minimum value $r_{\min}$ of $r$ on $(0,\infty)$, note the following:

- for $t_0:=\frac{33617680}{32158047}$, we have $r'(t_0-10^{-10})<0<r'(t_0+10^{-10})$ and hence the $r_{\min}=r(t_1)$ for some $t_1\in(t_0-10^{-10},t_0+10^{-10})$.
- $f_0>0$, $g_0>0$, $f'_0<0$, and $g'_0<0$, so that
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  r_{\min}=r(t_1)\le\frac{f_0(t_0)}{g_0(t_0)}
  &=0.40360349064\ldots, \\ 
  r_{\min}=r(t_1)>\frac{f_0(t_0+10^{-10})}{g_0(t_0-10^{-10})}
  &=0.40360349038\ldots.
  \end{aligned}
  $$

Comment: If I understood correctly, your argument implies that we can in fact take $c_2 = 1$ and $c_1 = r(x)$ where $x$ is the point where the we move from "down" to "up"; i.e., $x = \mathrm{argmin}_{y > 0} r(y)$. Are you able to bound $c_1$ from below via your argument?

Comment: @DrewBrady : I have added the requested details.

Comment: Thanks; your linked paper is also quite elegant---I just had a read through of your main results now.

Comment: @DrewBrady : Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret the question a bit more broadly as *"find an accurate approximation to $f(t)$ with proved bounds"*, then you might be helped by the paper [Approximating Mills ratio](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.3433) (2013).
It provides a systematic approach to obtain rational or algebraic approximations, such as
$$\frac{\pi(1+t^2)}{\sqrt{t^2+2\pi}+(\pi-1)t}-t<f(t)<\frac{\pi(1+t^2)}{\sqrt{(\pi-2)^2t^2+2\pi}+2t}-t.$$

Here is a plot of $f(t)$ (blue) and these upper and lower bounds (orange and green, nearly indistinguishable on the scale of the plot). The approximation $g(t)$ (red) from the OP is only accurate for large $t$.

[image]

Comment: The question, "based on numerics", was "Is it possible to show this formally?" Then, why is this an answer to the question? What I see here is only more (or the same?) numerics.

Comment: What do you mean by the "the" and by the "exact" in "the exact bounds"? Also, yes, there are a million bounds on the Mills ratio -- but the bounds you gave are not the bounds in question.

Comment: "If I interpret the question a bit more broadly as ..." -- I think the posted question "Is it possible to show this formally?" is quite clear and unambiguous, and thus leaves no room for interpretation. Especially if the "interpretation" is not really an interpretation.